# rows concatenate in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have following table.

[image]

I need to transform this input as you can see in below output example:
[image]

```
import pandas as pd

# Define the input data
data = {
    'ID': [500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 300, 200],
    'item': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'D', 'E'],
    'Counter': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
    'C': ['XX', 'XX', 'XX', 'XX', 'XX', 'YY', 'YY', 'YY', 'XX', 'XX', 'YY', 'YY', 'YY', 'XX', 'XX']
}

# Convert the input data to a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

If you have any ideas please share. Thank you very much!

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your I/O don't not match but (*based on your input screenshot*), you can try this :

```
out = (df.groupby(["ID", df["priority"].eq(1).cumsum(), "C"], as_index=False, sort=False)
          ["item"].agg("-".join).assign(ideal= lambda x: x.pop("item").str.cat(x.pop("C"), sep="-"))
      )
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

    ID         ideal
0  500  A-B-C-D-E-XX
1  500    A-B-C-E-YY
2  400        A-B-XX
3  400        A-C-YY
4  400          E-YY
5  300          D-XX
6  200          E-XX
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `cumsum` on the block start condition to identify the block, then `groupby` with `agg`:

```
out = (df.groupby(['ID',df['Counter'].eq(1).cumsum()], sort=False, as_index=False)
         .agg({'item':'-'.join, 'C':'first'})
         .assign(ideal=lambda x: x['item']+'-'+x['C'])
      )
print(out)
```

Output:

```
    ID       item   C         ideal
0  500  A-B-C-D-E  XX  A-B-C-D-E-XX
1  500      A-B-C  YY      A-B-C-YY
2  400        A-B  XX        A-B-XX
3  400        A-C  YY        A-C-YY
4  400          E  YY          E-YY
5  300          D  XX          D-XX
6  200          E  XX          E-XX
```

Comment: The cumsum trick is neat!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to group by the ID's and the "C" column as well as using the `eq(1).cumsum()` from the other answers. It cleverly helps to create common groups since any value of 1 for the Counter will create a new group. Then aggregate the strings by joining them with a hyphen separator. Then, reset the index so it falls back to a flat dataframe and optionally sort by the ID's to match your output.

```
out = df.groupby(['ID', 'C', df.Counter.eq(1).cumsum()])["item"].agg(lambda x : '-'.join(x)).reset_index().sort_values(by="ID", ascending=False)
```

Outputs

```
    ID   C  Counter       item
5  500  XX        1  A-B-C-D-E
6  500  YY        2      A-B-C
2  400  XX        3        A-B
3  400  YY        4        A-C
4  400  YY        5          E
1  300  XX        6          D
0  200  XX        7          E
```

Then,

```
out["ideal"] = out["item"] + "-" + out["C"]

    ID   C  Counter       item         ideal
5  500  XX        1  A-B-C-D-E  A-B-C-D-E-XX
6  500  YY        2      A-B-C      A-B-C-YY
2  400  XX        3        A-B        A-B-XX
3  400  YY        4        A-C        A-C-YY
4  400  YY        5          E          E-YY
1  300  XX        6          D          D-XX
0  200  XX        7          E          E-XX
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It should be 3 rows for ID=400 / please take a look at my output

Comment: Indeed, I missed the other solution, if you add the cumsum in the groups it'll work though!